# Wait until CSS changes (resizing) have taken effect before continuing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, size

I have a script that changes the size of a canvas to fit the image that is being loaded on it, and then downloads the image from the canvas. I need to resize it, or else the downloaded image includes any whitespace around it and looks smaller than it should.

```
originalImg.onload = function() {

    var width = originalImg.width;
    var height = originalImg.height;

    $("#myCanvas").css({ "height": height + "px", "width": width + "px", "margin-bottom": -height + "px" });

    var c = viewer.drawer.canvas;

    c.toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, '@Model.DatabaseName' + '.jpg');
    }); 
}
originalImg.src = originalSrc;
```

But when the image downloads, it still has all the whitespace. My script is completing before the canvas actually resizes, even though I resize it at the beginning. How can I make the canvas actually resize before completing the rest of the script?

edit: I can see by stepping through the script that the whole script finishes before the canvas actually changes size on the page.

Comment: The `css()` method should be synchronous (unless you have `transitions` applied in CSS). Could you supply an example of the issue in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: No, I really can't. My page is loading DZI images on a seadragon viewer that require an access key that is retrieved by the server. I can't replicate it on jsfiddle.

Comment: put `console.log` info or `alert` inside the `originalImg.onload` function to see it actually gets into the code.

Comment: I know it's hitting it, I've stepped through it and the saveAs() function wouldn't trigger if it wasn't getting into that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the CSS for the canvas but that only changes the size it displays at on screen, not the actual size of the canvas element itself. You can scale a canvas element using CSS without altering its content.

Try creating a new canvas element for each image after it's loaded, and set that canvas to be the correct size for that image and you should find it saves out correctly.

If you want to keep the graphical representation of your image in your existing canvas / markup that's no problem, you could copy the image to both, and have the "working" canvas hidden away from view.